# Table per subclass mapping strategy: switching tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

In a table per concrete subclass setup, is it possible to switch a row/object from one table to another? How would that work?

For example we have a base class Person.java with pk person_id. 
Then we have 2 subclasses Police.java and Firefighter.java both of these are mapped by corresponding tables PERSON and FIREFIGHTER again with primary key person_id.

Now suppose a Police officer becomes a firefighter or vice-verca, how will this work? Can this work in hibernate? Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

All common rows have to be identical in the different tables. In that strategy you have to duplicate rows. The only interesting illustration I found is in [The Java Geek](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/17/jpa-table-per-concrete-class-example/).

According to the [Java EE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html#bnbqv), the support of this strategy is optional (not available in Glassfish they say).

Polymorphism is poorly supported, so your use case wouldn't be satisfied properly: you would have to remove your policeman from the police before creating a brand new firefighter.

I guess you won't find what what you are looking for with another strategy if you want to switch between different rows among the different entities:

- In the Joined Subclass Strategy all common fields have to be mapped in the base table
- In the Single Table per Class Hierarchy Strategy (poor designation) you have all data in a single table with a discriminator column